# Vue conditional display

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I run this script :

```
<div class="description text-left" v-for="cases in siteObject">
  <div class="description text-left" v-for="item in siteObject.cases">
    <small><strong>{{item.x_con_title}}</strong> </small>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this result :

```
Closed
Closed
Closed
Open-Dispatch
Closed
Closed
Closed
```

I don't want to show the closed. I have tried with this condition:

```
Cases() {
  return this.siteObject.Cases.filter(info => info.x_con_title === "Open-Dispatch");
}
```

but nothing changes; I have always the same result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. - You can use the `<>` snippet editor and include vue.js

Comment: is it `siteObject.cases` or `siteObject.Cases` ? .. better name this computed property `Cases()` (if what's what it is) differently to avoid confusion and make it easier for yourself (because you already have a value `siteObject.Cases` I assume - the full list), you can name this one something like: `filteredCases() { ... }`. you filter method is ok btw

Comment: Why do you loop `cases in siteObject` and then `item in siteObject.cases`? Do you mean `item in cases` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the display layer (the template) handle this by using [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) directive for conditional rendering.

```
<div class="description text-left" v-for="cases in siteObject">
  <div class="description text-left" v-for="item in siteObject.cases">
    <small v-if="item.x_con_title != 'Closed'"><strong>{{item.x_con_title}}</strong> </small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `v-if` directive to achieve what you need. Also, your outer `for` loop is unnecessary since you are not doing anything with `cases`:

```
<div v-if="item.x_con_title !== 'Closed'" 
     class="description text-left" v-for="item in siteObject.cases">

    <small><strong>{{ item.x_con_title }}</strong> </small>
</div>
```